# How can I add a column to a dataframe that is based on another columns value?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

For school I have a DataFrame (containing of multiple columns and rows) and my task is to create a new column in that DataFrame that contains 'true' if the value of a column in that dataframe is higher than a certain value and the new column should contain 'false' if the value is lower than the value from a column in the dataframe. Can somebody please help me out? 
(I'm supposed to do this in jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can't really help without seeing some example data and code that you've tried so far. In the meantime, it sounds like you are looking for this kind of thing: `df['flag'] = df['value'] > threshold_value`.

Comment: You can compare each element in a column of a dataframe to a number by using `df['whatever the name of the column here'] > my_favourite_value`

Comment: Okay, let's say this is my dataframe    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 2, 4], 'B': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']}). Then I need to create a new column 'name doesnt matter'. And if the values of column A are equal to or bigger than 2, then my new column 'name doesnt matter' should contain 'false'. And if the values of column A are less than 2 then my new column should contain 'true'.  @PeterLeimbigler

Comment: Does your dataframe really store numeric values as the English word for each number, in string form?

Comment: If i understand correctly, no it doesn't. My numeric values are not stored in string form. @PeterLeimbigler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
df['flag'] = True
df.loc[df['A']>2,'flag'] = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
df[<new col>] = np.where(df[<value col>] > <threshold>, True, False)
```

But replace `<new col>` with the string name of your new column, `<value col>` with the string name of the column you're comparing, and replace `<threshold>` with the compared value.